# how to compare elements of 2 arrays in row

Tags: perl

I have 2 arrays (`@curNodes` and `@oldNodes`), elements of array are in row.
For e.g :

```
Output of print @curNodes   Output of print @oldNodes  
US                          London
UK                          US
```

Now I want to compare each element of `@curNodes` with `@oldNodes`.
E.g first it will check for `"US"` in `@oldNodes`, if it is there do nothing
else some other action.

Could you please help me and let me know if elements are in row, 
how this comparison can be done.

Comment: `US London UK US`, which array contains what? Format your question well.

Comment: What do you want to do if they are duplicates in one of the arrays?

Comment: In your description, you specify to check that the elements of `@curNodes` are in `@oldNodes`. Are we also suppose to check if the elements of `@oldNodes` are in `@curNodes`?

Comment: Both curNodes & oldnodes are 2 D arrays.@curNodes contains  $curNodes[0][0]=US , $curNodes[0][1]=UK in different rows. 
oldNodes array contains $oldNodes[0][0]=London , $oldNodes[0][1]=US. 
I want that each element of CurNodes  is compared with all elements oldNodes i.e $curNodes[0][0] will first be compared
with  $oldNodes[0][0], and then $oldNodes[0][1]. If there is a match do nothing else print something.and then compare 
$curNodes[0][1] with $oldNodes[0][0], and then $oldNodes[0][1].
:)

Answer (score 5):

For an approach not requiring any external modules, how about making the first array into a hash and then iterating through the second array? See below.

```
use v5.012;
use warnings;

my @old_nodes = qw/ a b c d /;
my %old = map {; $_ => 1 } @old_nodes;

my @cur_nodes = qw/ a d /;

foreach (@cur_nodes) {
    if ($old{$_}) {
        say "$_ exists in old_nodes";
    }
}
```

Comment: Both curNodes & oldnodes are 2 D arrays.@curNodes contains  $curNodes[0][0]=US , $curNodes[0][1]=UK in different rows. 
oldNodes array contains $oldNodes[0][0]=London , $oldNodes[0][1]=US. 
I want that each element of CurNodes  is compared with all elements @oldNodes i.e $curNodes[0][0] will first be compared
with  $oldNodes[0][0], and then $oldNodes[0][1]. If there is a match do nothing else print something.and then compare 
$curNodes[0][1] with $oldNodes[0][0], and then $oldNodes[0][1].

Comment: OK. If it's an array of arrays should we also be checking $oldNodes[1][27] ? If not, then `my %old = map {; $_ => 1 } @{ $oldNodes[0] }` would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Array::Diff** module for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the smart match operator (~~).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
my @curNodes = qw' US UK ';
my @oldNodes = qw' London US ';

my $flag;

foreach my $item (@curNodes) {
  $flag = @oldNodes~~$item ? 0 : 1;
  last if !$flag; #perform some action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't really have multidimensional arrays in Perl.
But there is certainly arrays of array references.

Assuming that you're running Perl 5.10 or newer, I think the smartmatch operator makes sense.

Based on your description, here's what I came up with:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @curNodes = (
    [ 'US', 'UK' ],
);

my @oldNodes = (
    [ 'London',  'US' ],
);

my @matchedElements = grep { $_ ~~ @{ $oldNodes[0] } } @{ $curNodes[0] };

say Dumper( \@curNodes );
say Dumper( \@oldNodes );
say Dumper( \@matchedElements );
```

This emits:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'US',
            'UK'
          ]
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          [
            'London',
            'US'
          ]
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          'US'
        ];
```

I imagine that you'd want to iterate over @matchedElements in your program.